# How do I work around lock contention in Apache Http Client

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm working on optimizing my metadata service which talks to the database. One of the bottleneck I found was threads were timing out waiting for a connection from the connection pool (timeout = 1s). On closer investigation of stack dump, it seems there are a lot of threads stuck waiting for the lock inside org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.

ApacheHttpClient: 4.5.x

ApacheHttpCore: 4.4.x

MaxNumberOfConnection: 900

Connection timeout: 1s

Any ideas to overcome this bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can consider another approach.
900 http requests too heavy for one service provider.
for famous servlet container (tomcat or jetty),it can handle 300-500 request connection concurrently .

you can deploy two or three service providers to form a cluster, use nginx or apache http server to dispatch request.